# The rail gun experiment revisited

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electric-circuits

A metal rod is closing a horizontal electric circuit [as shown here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Rail_gun.jpg). We apply a vertical magnetic induction $B$ as shown. The magnetic (Laplace) force on the rod is $F=I\ell B$ to the right. If $F$ is greater than the friction, the rod will start moving.

What happens if the $B$ field is to the right? The Laplace force is now vertical and if it is greater than the weight of the rod, will the rod oscillate?

Comment: Is the rod constrained to move in one dimension along the rails?

Comment: @probably_someone the rod is free, just sitting on the circuit.

Comment: And is the rail assembly fixed or free (i.e. does it react to the torque that the magnetic field will exert on it)?

Comment: @probably_someone It's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When the rod is in contact with the rails, the current through the loop exerts a torque (provided by two equal and opposite forces on the rod and the portion of the rails parallel to it, where the direction of the force is dependent on the direction of the current through the loop). If the rail assembly is fixed, then we can ignore the force on the rails and concentrate on the rod.

Suppose the current direction is counterclockwise, so that the resulting magnetic force on the rod points downward. Then nothing happens.

Suppose the current direction is clockwise, so that the resulting magnetic force on the rod points upwards. Then, if the magnetic force is greater than the weight of the rod, the rod will accelerate upward. But as soon as it leaves the rails, it breaks the circuit, meaning that there will be no more magnetic force on the rod, so it will immediately fall back down to the rails*, where it will complete the circuit again and rise for a moment. Depending on the strength of the current, the rod's behavior could range anywhere from vibration against the rails to repeated jumping off of the rails.

*If it jumps far enough off of the rails, then there's always a chance that perturbations from e.g. the movement of the air or slight variations in the Earth's surface gravity could cause it to rotate slightly and fall through the rails. After that, of course, nothing happens.

EDIT: In order to calculate the period and amplitude of the oscillations, you would need to know how much total momentum the rod acquires from the magnetic force (in other words, the *impulse*). If you know the net force on the rod as a function of time, this is equivalent to

$$\Delta p=\int F(t)dt$$

Equivalently, if you know the average net force on the wire $\overline{F}$ over a time period of interest $\Delta t$, then you can also calculate the impulse using $\Delta p=\overline{F}\Delta t$.

Once you have the impulse, then you can calculate the amplitude, assuming no air resistance, using straightforward trajectory calculations. A rod of mass $m$ will have an initial velocity $v_0=\frac{\Delta p}{m}$, which means that, under gravitational acceleration, it will reach its peak height after a time $t_{peak}=\frac{v_0}{g}$, under the acceleration of gravity. This gives the oscillations an amplitude of

$$A=v_0 t_{peak}-\frac{1}{2}gt_{peak}^2=\frac{v_0^2}{2g}=\frac{\Delta p^2}{2gm^2}$$

The period of the oscillations is simply twice the time it takes for the rod to reach its peak height, because the motion of the rod is symmetric about this point. As such, the period is

$$T=2t_{peak}=\frac{2v_0}{g}=\frac{2\Delta p}{mg}$$

if you assume that the wire instantly jumps when it hits the rail, which is true for a light wire with very little inductance, but is not necessarily true in general.

To *actually calculate* the impulse imparted to the wire, you must take many physical things into account. I will attempt a very crude example calculation below, making the following assumptions:

- The resistance of the rails is zero.
- The surface dynamics of the rod-rail interface are irrelevant (i.e. the contact resistance between them is zero).
- The rod can dissipate current normally through its ends, even after being disconnected from the circuit.
- The rod's resistance $R$, length $\ell$, and radius $r$, and its distance from the voltage source $x$ are known, and the radius of the rails is the same as the radius of the rod.
- The power source provides a fixed voltage $V$, without any internal resistance.
- There is no air resistance.
- The relative permeability $\mu_r$ of the rod and rails used is known and the same.
- The impulse imparted by gravity while the wire is accelerating upward is negligible.

Making those assumptions, then, the problem becomes: calculate the current through the rod if it is subject to a voltage $V$ for a certain time and then the voltage source is switched off after that time. Our circuit, being a wire loop, is essentially an LR circuit. The resistance $R$ is just the resistance of the wire, while the inductance $L$ is the inductance of the loop, which is (https://www.eeweb.com/tools/rectangle-loop-inductance):

$$L_{loop}=\frac{\mu_0\mu_r}{\pi}\left(-2(x+\ell)+2\sqrt{x^2+\ell^2}-\ell\ln\left[\frac{\ell+\sqrt{x^2+\ell^2}}{x}\right]-x\ln\left[\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+\ell^2}}{\ell}\right]+\ell\ln\left[\frac{2\ell}{r}\right]+x\ln\left[\frac{2x}{r}\right]\right)$$

If the voltage is switched on at time $t=0$, we know that the current will be

$$I_{chg}(t)=\frac{V}{R}\left(1-e^{-t\frac{R}{L_{loop}}}\right)$$

so the magnetic force will be

$$F(t)=I_{chg}(t)\ell B=\frac{V\ell B}{R}\left(1-e^{-t\frac{R}{L_{loop}}}\right)$$

The rod does not move until the force $F(t)$ reaches its weight $mg$, which is at the time

$$t_{lift}=\frac{L_{loop}}{R}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{mgR}{V\ell B}}\right)$$

As you can see, if we have $\frac{mgR}{V\ell B}>1$, then the value of $t_{lift}$ is undefined. This is because in those situations, the force will never grow large enough to equal the rod's weight, and oscillations will never happen. Therefore, we shall assume $\frac{mgR}{V\ell B}<1$ from now on.

After time $t_{lift}$, the wire lifts off of the rails, which means the net force on it is now nonzero, and the inductance is now the inductance of a straight wire (https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/wire-self-inductance-calculator/):

$$L_{rod}=2\ell\mu_0\left(\ln\left[\frac{\ell}{r}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{r}{\ell}\right)^2}\right)\right]-\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{r}{\ell}\right)^2}+\frac{\mu_r}{4}+\frac{r}{\ell}\right)$$

Now, according to our assumptions, the current discharges from the rod in the same way as if it were connected to a circuit with no voltage source (note: this is pretty unrealistic), which means, if the rod starts discharging at time $t=0$, the current through the rod is

$$I_{dchg}(t)=I_0e^{-t\frac{R}{L_{rod}}}$$

which means the force on the rod is now

$$F(t)=I_{dchg}(t)\ell B = I_0\ell B e^{-t\frac{R}{L_{rod}}}$$

But we know what $I_0$ is, since it's the current at the moment the rod left the rails:

$$I_0=I_{chg}(t_{lift})=\frac{V}{R}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{mgR}{V\ell B}\right)\right)=\frac{mg}{\ell B}$$

and the total impulse imparted by the magnetic force is

$$\Delta p=\int_0^\infty F(t)dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{mg}{\ell B} e^{-t\frac{R}{L_{rod}}}dt=\frac{mgL_{rod}}{\ell BR}$$

This means that its oscillations have an amplitude of

$$A=\frac{gL_{rod}^2}{2\ell^2 B^2 R^2}$$

while the rod stays in the air for the time

$$T=\frac{2L_{rod}}{\ell B R}$$

and stays on the rails for the time $t_{lift}$, for a total period of $T+t_{lift}$.

Comment: I was looking for some details and calculations. Like what are the period and amplitude of the vibration (I already mentioned in the question that it will oscillate).

Comment: As classical physics does not like discontinuities (full current to zero current) I tend to believe that as the bar decreases pressure on the rails, resistance will increase, current will decrease. A steady state will be reached whereby the decreased force will equal weight.

Comment: @inéquation The period and amplitude of the vibration are not possible to calculate without much further details about the specific physical situation, because they depend on the _impulse_ imparted to the rod by the action of the force, and knowing the impulse requires knowing the force on the rod as a function of time. In the ideal situation considered here, the force would be a delta function multiplied by a very situation-dependent constant, which doesn't give us any information about the impulse.

Comment: @inéquation If we want to calculate the force as a function of time, then we must be able to calculate the current as a function of time. This requires us to know things like the resistance of the wire in the loop, the inductance of the loop itself, the behavior of the electrons in the rod in the moments after it leaves the rail, the surface dynamics of the rod-rail interface (in case the resistance or inductance change with pressure), etc. That said, if you somehow know the impulse, then you can calculate the period and amplitude. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: @inéquation A rough calculation, making many assumptions, is now included.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is nontrivial only if the framework is fixed and the rod is free to move in the two obvious directions. In that case, for a horizontal magnetic field, I would say that if the Lorentz force is greater than the weight, the rod will rise up for a split second, lose contact with the circuit making the lorentz force zero and it will fall down again and by the inertia of motion it will fall below the circuit after which there's no rescue.

Comment: "By the inertia of motion it will fall below the circuit" - why couldn't it land back on the rails?

Comment: It will rise for a split second it will collide with the rails. Also how far will it rise?

Comment: @probably_someone it does land back on the rails but im assuming that it will fall with a velocity which will take it through the rail.

Comment: @inequation I dont know how far it will rise. The problem is that theres a discontinuity in the force on the rod at the point where it leaves the rail, so my reasoning goes haywire there.